# How do I make vim's autoindent not drop trailing spaces?

Tags: vim, text-editors, indentation, autoindent

In some text editors (e.g. Kate, gedit), when auto indent is enabled, pressing return twice will leave a trailing whitespace (which I want):

```
if (code) {
....
....|
}
```

While others cater to the coding standard where trailing spaces (even in blank lines) aren't allowed:

```
if (code) {

....|
}
```

What annoys me about this is that if I arrow up after auto-indenting, the auto-indent is lost:

```
if (code) {
|
....
}
```

If I run vim and `:set autoindent` , I get the latter behavior.

My question is, how do I set vim to keep the trailing spaces rather than automatically removing them if they go unused?

Comment: My initial reaction is that you're doing it wrong. By leaving blank lines indented like that you kill the possibility to use `{` or `}` (e.g. `d{` etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this hint](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_correct_indent_for_new_lines_despite_blank_lines) on the `vim` wiki for how to have correct indention even for empty lines. If you just want to keep the previous indent (ignoring what `vim` calculated as the correct indent) use `let ind = indent(prevnonblank(v:lnum - 1))` like explained in a comment under the same wiki entry.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/250762/customize-autoindent-settings-in-vimrc-file/250808#250808) to work for me:

```
:inoremap <Return> <Space><BS><Return>
```

Comment: This looks like a hack/workaround. Isn't there a proper option to turn off that "unindent blank line" behaviour?

Comment: Not that I know of - otherwise I would've posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

In my .vimrc:

```
" Change a blank line upon creation so that its leading spaces won't be removed
inoremap <Return> <Return><Space><BS>
nnoremap o o<Space><BS>
nnoremap O O<Space><BS>
```